# Schrödinger's equation denumerable eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

The Schrödinger's equation can be written in this form:

$-u''(x)+V(x) u(x) = E u(x) $

$V(x)$ is a function that is defined on the real line. We know ${u}^{2}$ is integrable on the whole real line. We are interested in determining $E$.
Here is my question: under what condition(s) on $V$ and/or $u$, allowed numbers for $E$ are denumerable? (As I have studied in quantum mechanics, we are expected eigen-energies to be denumerable in physical(?) situations.)

Comment: In order to have only bound states, i.e., discrete spectrum, a strong potential is typically required, something resembling the potential for the harmonic oscillator $x^2$. It doesn't have to be quite as strong; it is enough to tend to $+\infty$ at $\pm\infty$ as a similar power of $x$.

Comment: @TrialAndError so you say when the potential tends infinity the spectrum is discrete, yeah? Where can I find a proof for this? Thanks

Comment: @k-n-o : An old reference: Titchmarsh, "Eigenfunction Expansions Associated with Second Order Differential Equations".

Comment: @TrialAndError I found the answer and I am so glad. Thanks again

Comment: Think this question would get an good answer in Physics.SE